# Merging two XML files using XSL transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I've been trying to merge two xml files into another XML with the output of both combined using XSL but haven't been able to. The xml's are quite large, so I'll only include a small portion.
I'm really lost on this task. I can transform a single XML file but merge two is something I have never done and can't find much information on it related to my specific case.

**XML 1:**

```
<Games>
    <Game>
        <Date>01/05/2019</Date>
        <PlayerID>454asdsad</PlayerID>
        <Place>1</Place>
        <GameID>CpsQf125AFy</GameID>
        <Payment currency="gbp">50</Payment>
    </Game>

    .....repeats the above many times with different values.
</Games>
```

**XML 2:**

```
<Players>
    <Player>
        <Title>Mr</Title>
        <Lastname>Doe</Lastname>
        <Firstname>John</Firstname>
        <IDnumber>454asdsad</IDnumber>
        <Address>Streetname</Address>
    </Player>

   .....repeats the above many times with different values.
</Players>
```

**Expected result:**

```
<Games>
      <Place>
        <Date>
          <Game>
            <Title>Mr</prefix>
            <Lastname>Doe</Lastname>
            <Firstname>John</Firstname>
            <IDnumber>454asdsad</IDnumber>
            <Address>Streetname</Address>
            <Date>01/05/2019</Date>
            <PlayerID>454asdsad</Player>
            <Place>1</Place>
            <GameID>CpsQf125AFy</GameID>
            <Payment currency="gbp">50</Payment>
          </Game>
       </Date>

       <Date> ...if there are more dates is the same place as above.
          <Game>
               ....information
          </Game>
       </Date>

     </Place>

     <Place> ...another place
       <Date>
         <Game>
            ...all the information like above, with the appropriate next values from both XML's.
         </Game>
       </Date>

       <Date> ...if there are more dates is the same place as above.
         <Game>
              ....information
         </Game>
       <Date>
     </Place>

     ...repeats same thing and format until the end.
 </Games>
```

Comment: Does your processor support XSLT 2.0? -- P.S. An element's name cannot start with a digit; if that's really what your XML 2 looks like, you won't be able to do anything with it in XSLT.

Comment: It should be able to yes. Yeah I know about the tags, that was my mistake. It shouldn't be in the end result, forgot to remove it them.

Comment: What determines which elements are to be merged? Just their position? Or any element value? I can't identify any merge or grouping keys in that sample data that the elements from both input seem to have in common.

Comment: And also state which XSLT processor and/or XSLT version you can use as XSLT 3 for instance has `xsl:merge` and in XSLT 2 `for-each-group` can easily work with nodes from different documents (whereas Muenchian grouping in XSLT 1 being key-based is harder with different documents).

Comment: Basically they are connected by the "PlayerID" in one and the "IDNumber" in the other. If they exist in both, then it joins the information.
XSLT 2 would be the ideal one. I'm not sure I can use 3.0 nor have I used before. I've used for-each before just have no idea how to work and apply it with 2 separate xml's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to this:

- grouping, first on place and then on date
- joining, fetching in data from the second file selected by personID.

The grouping is basically

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Game" group-by="Place">
  <Place>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="Date">
      <Date>
        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
          <Game>
             XXXXX
             <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
```

And at XXXXX you need to do the join, which is basically

```
<xsl:copy-of select="key('player-id', PlayerID, $players-xml')/*"/>
```

where $players-xml is the Players.xml document, and the key is defined as

```
<xsl:key name="player-id" match="Player" use="IDNumber"/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped a lot. Wasn't as easy as I thought because of the way I needed things to be organized and displated, but with the structure you gave me I managed to find a way :)

Answer (score 1):

If you know about `for-each-group`, then you should have no problems to pull in elements from both documents with e.g. `<xsl:for-each-group select="/Games/Game, doc('file2.xml')/Players/Player" group-by="PlayerID, IDnumber">`, the grouping key will by `PlayerID` where that element exists and `IDnumber` where that elements exists, as long as there are no elements having both child elements that approach should be safe or could be corrected to `group-by="(PlayerID, IDnumber)[1]"` to select one key if not.

And if there is also the need to group by `Place` you can nest another `for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="Place"` or use a composite key.

Comment: I've used for-each, but never for-each-group. But I will give it a try. This is still really new to me.

Comment: Using this does what you said, its progress. But its only outputting Games xml and the IDnumbers from Players xml. When I try to manually add them they don't output or output out of the loop. I know I'm close but not sure how to make them all display from boths lists now